# sharing a perlbrew installation among multiple users

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I want to setup a single Perlbrew installation to share among my team, so they don't all have to compile versions of Perl separately. So I set PERLBREW_ROOT and then installed Perlbrew on a network drive. Then I started sourcing the bashrc from my .profile-user file.

So far so good, but I'm not sure what to tell them to do. The documentation says every user needs to run "perlbrew init" first, but I never did that myself. Everything I did is in the first paragraph.

At any rate, what steps should I tell them to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, pass `-Duserelocatableinc` to `perlbrew` when installing a build of Perl to avoid problems that will arrise from differences in the paths used to access the installed `perl`.

---

If the other users simply want to use one of the `perlbrew`-installed builds of Perl, they simply need to point the shebang line of their script to the `perl` inside the `perlbrew` directory as usual.

For example, if `PERLBREW_ROOT` is `/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew` and the `perlbrew` label for the install is `feed_fetcher`, one would use

```
#!/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/feed_fetcher/bin/perl
```

---

If the other users also want to install modules and/or use scripts installed by modules (e.g. Module::CoreList's `corelist`, Unicode::Tussle's `uniprops`, etc),  they must also do the following:

1. In their login script, add

   ```
   export PERLBREW_ROOT=/.../perl5/perlbrew
   ```
2. In their shell startup script, add

   ```
   source "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/etc/bashrc
   ```

You can technically skip the first step, but only if the path hardcoded in `etc/bashrc` is correct for that user.

Comment: What is `"${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"` all about? why not just source /.../perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc?

Comment: Also you didn't mention perlbrew init, should I be telling them to run that too?

Comment: As for my first comment I don't understand the syntax of `:-`

Comment: Re "*Also you didn't mention perlbrew init*", That wasn't a mistake.

Comment: Re "*I don't understand the syntax of `:-`*", It provides a default if `PERLBREW_ROOT` isn't set.

Comment: Re "*why not just source /.../perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc?*", Hardcoding the path twice just leads to more problems. If you're going to set `PERLBREW_ROOT`, you might as well use it.